# $u_{n+1} = a u_n +b u_{n-1} +c$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Is there a closed form formula for the general term of a recurrence sequence satisfying $$u_{n+1} = a u_n +b u_{n-1} +c$$               The sequence I am interested in satisfies $u_{n+1} = 8 u_n - 3 u_{n-1}  -4$.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve any non-homogeneous, linear recurrence of the above form by converting it to homogeneous form.

(I'll use $n$ instead of $n+1$, doesn't matter anyway!)

$$u_{n}=au_{n-1}+bu_{n-2}+c$$
$$u_{n-1}=au_{n-2}+bu_{n-3}+c$$
Subtract them to get:-

$$u_{n}=(a+1)u_{n-1}+(b-a)u_{n-2}-bu_{n-3}$$
You can then use characteristic polynomial to find the answer.

---

Speaking strictly for the equation you wrote, the characteristic polynomial is
$$z^3=9z^2-11z+3$$ which has the roots
$$z=1, 4+\sqrt{13}, 4-\sqrt{13}$$ 
giving $$u_n=a_1+a_2{(4+\sqrt{13})}^n+a_3{(4-\sqrt{13})}^n$$, where $a_i$s depend on the initial condition.

Comment: So $u_n$ wouldn't converge? I find it a little bit strange.

Comment: @furyo It isn't strange at all. Stuff like this (convergence) depends on the initial conditions. Depending upon them, the series may or may not convegre!

Comment: For instance, if you take $u_1=u_2=1$, $u_i=1$ for all $i$, which is a convergent sequence. On the other hand, if you take $u_1=1, u_2=2$, then it'll be a divergent sequence.

Comment: I would've expected a non constant sequence increasing to $1$. Here it's either constant or divergent.

Comment: You can't get a non-constant, convergent sequence because it isn't constant $\implies $ at least one of $a_2, a_3$ is non-zero $\implies $ $u_n$ will be a strictly increasing/decreasing (depending upon sign of $a_i$s) function of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear difference equation so can be stated as

$$
u = u_h + u_p
$$

with

$$
u_h(n+1)-au_h(n)-bu_h(n-1) = 0\\
u_p(n+1)-au_p(n)-bu_p(n-1) = c\\
$$

now making $u_h(n) = \phi^n$ and substituting we have

$$
\phi^n\left(\phi-a-b\phi^{-1}\right) = 0
$$

so

$$
\phi = \frac{1}{2} \left(a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4 b}\right)
$$

and

$$
u_h(n) = \frac{C_1}{2^n} \left(a-\sqrt{a^2+4 b}\right)^n+\frac{C_2}{2^n} \left(a+\sqrt{a^2+4 b}\right)^n
$$

and also

$$
u_p(n) = \frac{c}{1-a-b}
$$

so finally

$$
u(n) =  \frac{C_1}{2^n} \left(a-\sqrt{a^2+4 b}\right)^n+\frac{C_2}{2^n} \left(a+\sqrt{a^2+4 b}\right)^n + \frac{c}{1-a-b}
$$